# How to write an XPath/xslt query to match two attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to match attribute(lb=prodbind and s=false) from below  XML:

```
< testResults version="1.2">

< sample na="2" ng="2" by="346" dt="text" tn="Thread Group 1-2" rm="javax.naming.CommunicationException: defaulthost:30 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: defaulthost]" rc="800" lb="ProdBind" s="false" ts="1468674969351" lt="0" t="2123"/>
```

Tried these options but no luck:

```
< xsl:variable name="prod1fail" select="count(/testResults/*[@lb = 'prodBind' and @s='false'])"/>

< xsl:variable name="prod1fail" select="count(//testResults/sample[@lb = 'prodBind' and @s='false'])"/>
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: "*no luck*" is not a good description of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

XML is case-sensitive: `"ProdBind"` is not the same thing as `"prodBind"`

If (and that's not at all clear from your question) you are trying to count how many `sample` elements meet the given criteria, then you should use:

```
count(/testResults/sample[@lb='ProdBind' and @s='false'])
```

---

Note also that an element name cannot start with a space - so if your input really has:

```
< testResults version="1.2">
```

then it's not an XML document and cannot be processed by XSLT at all.

Answer (score 0):

Small note that with some processors it will be faster to break the `and` into a sequence of filters:

```
count(/testResults/sample[@lb='ProdBind'][@s='false'])
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing, Mads.